# How can I get rid of this damn 403 error?

Tags: nginx, static

I've tried since hours with lots of solutions but cannot get rid of this 403 error on serving a static subdomain with NGINX.

I've tried chmod all my permissions in the directory to the static folder and editing the config file over and over.

NGINX serves beautifully my reverse proxied Node app but shuts down all the static subdomains that once were in the server.

Permissions:

`dr-xr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     home
drwx--x--x ca****8sh nginx    ca****8sh
lrwxrwxrwx ca****8sh ca****8sh www -> public_html
drwxr-x--- ca****8sh ca****8sh   public_html
drwxr-xr-x nginx    nginx    residenza******.******ano.ch;`

config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name  residenza******.******ano.ch;
    root         /home/ca****8sh/www/residenza******.******ano.ch/;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index        index.html;
        #autoindex on;
        #autoindex_exact_size off;
    }
```

[continues with SSL setup]

I've also tried tweaking things around like enabling autoindex but to no avail.

I'm on despair, please help!

Comment: I get these kind of errors in the logs: 2019/10/14 19:23:00 [error] 28268#0: *58 "/home/caq018sh/www/residenzasofia.casalugano.ch/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 178.197.232.141, server: 
residenzasofia.casalugano.ch, request: "GET /?fbclid=IwAR1fP1T4jAaxYEHbMQc3bayqQDQj0lauCo_bjWT8NstDdA_CGsfH-xtn9E4 HTTP/2.0", host: "residenzasofia.casalugano.ch", referrer: "http://m.facebook.com"

Comment: Yes I know I get the same error with the other subdomain it was an example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled by changing the global nginx user to a higher tier user. This is what was causing the permits issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check which user nginx is using in first line of nginx.conf. It should be either nginx or www-data. then run this command. Replace www-data with nginx if the user is nginx

```
chown -R www-data /home/ca****8sh/www/residenza******.******ano.ch/
```

If you are using SELinux like CentOS, run these commands too:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on 
chcon -Rt /home/ca****8sh/www/residenza******.******ano.ch/
```

Comment: Sigh it does not work!  The command goes through but I still get the 403 error.